# Why null hypothesis in t-tests can be numbers other than zero?

Tags: probability, statistics

This may sound stupid but please bear with me because it's hard to explain also hypothesis testing is a totally new concept to me and cannot really wrap my head around it

**Concern:**

Should not T-distributions be used **ONLY** to test $H_o: \Delta \mu = 0$ ?

**My reasoning:**

Because basically that's what these T-distributions are only **able** to test

Let me illustrate , say we ran a **paired t-test**  with **3** degrees of freedom and confidence interval of **95%** and $H_o: \Delta \mu = 0$ , $H_a: \Delta \mu \ne 0$ and we get **t-score = -3.908** which corresponds to **p-value = 0.015** and according to my "understanding" that means **1.5% of times "our null hypothesis"** which says that $\Delta \mu = 0$ is **true** so we can reject the null hypothesis with a 95% of confidence , right?

**BUT** and here's what i am trying to say:

We could have got the same **T-score** (because t-scores are simply the no. of standard deviations away from the hypothesized mean in the sampling distribution) but for a totally **"different" null hypothesis** (say $H_o: \Delta \mu = 3$) , so should not we construct a totally **new T-distrubtion** with it's own degress of freedom to test the **new null hypothesis** ($H_o: \Delta \mu = 3$) and same goes to all other null hypotheses, Why are we using a single disturbtion to test all possible null hypotheses ?

NOTE : I might be making wrong assumptions and of course feel free me to correct me but that's what i was able to grasp

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A different hypothesis requires a different test.  A t distribution is a particular shape suitable to estimation. I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor what i am saying is that we use the same t-distrubtions for different null hypotheses

Comment: No we don't. If your sample mean is 1 and your sample standard deviation is 1, a t test for $H_0 : \mu = 5$ gives a very different value from a t test for $H_0 : \mu = 0$.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor if you think about it , a distribution is made by repeating an experiment number of times so should not different null hypotheses have different t-distrubtions with it's own degrees of freedom cuz each null hypothesis represents a different experiment, it's hard to explain ik

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I get it , the test-stastic is different for both but we are still comparing two different null hypotheses to the same distribution,  that's what I am talking about

Comment: Are you asking why a t distribution's shape is not a function of its mean?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor exactly kind of what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\frac{\bar x-\mu}{s/\sqrt n}$ follows a t-distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom. Under the null hypothesis, we specify a particular value of $\mu$ that we think is the true population mean. Call it $\mu_0$. By extension, since this is assumed to be the true population mean, therefore $\frac{\bar x-\mu_0}{s/\sqrt n}$ follows a t distribution. If the sample mean $\bar x$ is far from the $\mu_0$, it is unlikely that we would have observed such an extreme sample mean under this t distribution, because the shape of the density is bell-shaped, meaning there is less density on the tails. It is not the fact that it is far from the $\mu_0$ that means that it is incorrect. The mean is only the expected value; it is possible that under another distribution, the farther you are away from $\mu_0$, the more density there is, and so the closer to $\mu_0$, the more unlikely you are to observe that value - for example, take a bimodal normal distribution. Anyway, since there is less density on the tails, we don't think that this distribution is correct. But what were we specifying for this distribution? Everything is fixed except for the mean. Therefore it must be the mean that is incorrect, and we reject the null mean.

There is no particular reason why you must test the hypothesis that $\mu_0=0$. It can be any value that you believe is the true population mean (see the very first sentence).

Comment: are you trying to say that t-distributions are based on the central limit theorm and adjusted by degrees of freedom and that's why we use them to test any null hypothesis?

Comment: does a t-distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom has the same standard deviation as my sampling distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom? (cuz u are saying that everything is fixed except for the mean)

Comment: The only parameter that determines a t distribution is its degrees of freedom. So yes, any t distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom has the same standard deviation. The mean is not a parameter of the t distribution. It arises when you construct a t-statistic. If you subtract the population mean from the sample mean and divide by the sample standard error divided by square root n, what you get comes from a t-distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom with mean 0 and variance $(n-1)/(n-3)$